# "Das ist eines ihrer beliebtesten Ferienziele." — Why is "eines" used here?

Tags: grammar

This is a sentence I found in Assimil, Chapter 37:

> Das ist eines ihrer beliebtesten Ferienziele.

*Ferienziele* is plural and genitive, so I understand why *ihrer beliebtesten* is there. But I can't work out why *eines* is used. *Eines* is used for masculine and neuter genitive, where *-(e)s* is appended to the noun, but that's not the case here.

Is it because *Ziel* would be neuter if it weren't plural here? I'm sure I've covered this in a grammar book before, but it has slipped my mind.

Comment: Für das Maskulinum würde 'einer' benutzt werden: "Einer meiner Lieblingsschuhe treibt die Spree hinunter." Wir haben eine Menge Ziele, und eines davon wird näher beschrieben, als zu den beliebtesten gehörend. Californien und Rio sind zwei ihrer beliebtesten Ferienziele. Californien, Rio und der Regenwald in Kamerun sind drei ihrer beliebtesten Ferienziele.

Comment: Yes, neuter (nominative singular) because of _das Ziel_: _**one** of their most popular destinations_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this sentences, they talk about *one* of the most favourite destinations.

*[Ferien]Ziel* is neuter in German (by the way, for the question of the correct gender it doesn't matter whether the word is used in singular or plural**).

You could now rephrase this sentence to:

> Das ist ein Ferienziel ihrer beliebtesten Ferienziele.

And you can replace *ein Ferienziel* by the corresponding neuter indefinite pronoun *eines*.

> Das ist eines ihrer beliebtesten Ferienziele.

You can compare this to the following sentences of same structure with different genders:

> Das ist einer ihrer Lieblingspullover.
>   Das ist eine ihrer Lieblingshosen.
>   Das ist eines ihrer Lieblingsgetränke.

---

** That is one reason why guessing the gender from the noun doesn't work in many cases, but you need to know the gender to find the correct form of the noun. Example:

> Hosen
>   Spatzen

Both look similar and both *can be* nominative plural of *Hose* and *Spatz*. However, *die Hose* is female und *der Spatz* is male.

Comment: "Das ist ein Ferienziel ihrer beliebtesten Ferienziele." - maybe it's just me, but this does not sound like the same statement to me. No matter how often I re-read this sentence, I am always getting the impression it says that "their favourite holiday destinations" have one or more holiday destinations of their own (whatever this is supposed to mean). I don't think you can simply replace *eines* like this. Compare a similar sentence: "Das ist ein Kunde seiner beliebtesten Kunden." has a different meaning from "Das ist einer seiner beliebtesten Kunden."

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether *Ziel* is used as singular or plural, it always applies the rules of a neuter noun.

So you said correctly that *Ferienziele* is genitive and the neuter **[indefinite pronoun](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ein#Indefinitpronomen)** of *ein* is *eines*.

***Some of the following examples are only loosely translated!***

> Das ist **eines** ihrer beliebtesten Ferienziele. *(neuter, nominative)*
>   *[This is **one of** her favorite vacation destinations.]*
>
> **Einer** ist übrig, zwei habe ich verloren. *(masculine, nominative)* *[**One** is left, I’ve lost two.]*
>
> Bis auf **eine** sind alle Schülerinnen da. *(feminine, accusative)* *[Except for **one** all students are here.]*
>
> Könnte mir **einer** Hilfe leisten? *(masculine, nominative)* *[Could **someone** give me assistance?]*
>
> Darf ich auch so **ein[e]s** haben? *(neuter, accusative)* *[Can I have **one** like this too?]*
>
> Was für **ein(e)s** hätten Sie denn gern? *(neuter, accusative)* *Which **one** would you like?*
>
> Wenn es **einem** nicht gut geht, sollte man sich im Verzicht üben. *(masculine, dative)* *[If **someone** doesn’t feel well, one should practice self-denial.]*
>
> Davon wird **einem** ja schlecht! *(masculine, dative)* *[This makes **one** feel sick!]*
>
> Die **eine** geht, die andere bleibt. *(feminine, nominative)* *[**One** goes, one stays.]*
>
> In dieser Gemeinschaft hilft **einer** dem anderen. *(masculine, nominative)* *[In this community **one** helps the other.]*

Comment: _Ein, eine, ein_ is an article, _einer, eine, eines_ is an indefinite pronoun. Therefore it’s wrong to say _eines_ is the neutral form of _ein_.

Comment: Well, of course it is a neutral form in this case. If you said _Das ist **einer** meiner Hunde._ it is masculine.

Comment: Yes, but it is not a form of _ein_.