# function of "eines" in "eines der größten Abwehr-Talente in Europa"

Tags: grammar-identification

I was reading an article containing the following passage:

> Ozan ist eines der größten Abwehr-Talente in Europa in seinem Alter

This to me reads

> Ozan is one of the biggest Defensive-Talents in Europe for his age.

My confusion lies in the use of eines.

I tried to work out whether "eines" in this passage is a numeral, article or pronoun.

I don't think it is a numeral as it doesn't denote a number specifically.

I don't think it is an article because it doesn't function as "the" in some sense.

I thought it was a pronoun but couldn't work out what case it was referring to.

Wiktionary tells me it functions as a genitive masculine pronoun but I can't work out how eines is used in this sentence.

I read this [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27806/eines-vs-ein-in-eines-der-probleme) but couldn't work out if eines was substituting a noun.

What is eines functioning as in this sentence?

Comment: Another similar question: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27608/das-ist-eines-ihrer-beliebtesten-ferienziele-why-is-eines-used-here

Comment: And [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/eines#Deklinierte_Form,_Indefinitpronomen) should have told you that it can be Nominativ, Akkusativ, or Genitiv. Or maybe you didn't realise that it is "**das** Talent"?
No complaint, btw, you obviously did your research.

Answer (score 8):

The verb *sein* needs two nominatives: a subject and a [predicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_complement).

Therefore, *eines* must be a nominative neuter singular pronoun. Compare:

> Das ist ein wichtig**es** Thema. (*article, ending on the adjective*)
>
> Es gibt nicht viele wichtige Themen, aber der Klimawandel ist ein**es**/ein**s**. (*pronoun, with ending*)

In the above example, *ein(e)s* is interpreted as *ein wichtiges Thema* because of *viele wichtige Themen* in the preceding sentence.

In your example, the gender of the pronoun is determined by the genitive noun phrase that follows, i.e. *der größten Abwehrtalente*. Since *Talent* is neuter, we get *ein(e)s*.

Two further examples exhibiting a masculine and a feminine pronoun. The examples have been chosen to unequivocally show that the gender of the pronoun is determined by the gender of the noun in the genitive phrase that follows.

> Er ist ein**e** der größten Koryphäen (*fem.*) auf diesem Gebiet.
>   Sie ist ein**er** der glücklichsten Menschen (*masc.*), die ich kenne.